# Javascript dec to hex

Tags: javascript, hex, decimal

```js
var dec = prompt("Enter a number");

if (dec != null && dec > 0) {
 var hex = dec.toString(16);
 alert(hex);
}
else {
 alert("number must be greater than 0");
}
```

I have the following code
and when I enter a number into the prompt it alerts the same number
Example: I enter 256
Alert: 256

Comment: and? What is your question?

Comment: OP wants to know why it is alerting wrong value @Whitefret

Comment: sorry was in review, didn't see the posted answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `prompt` will return a `string`. Just convert it to a plain `number` first.

```
var dec = +prompt("Enter a number");

if (dec != null && dec > 0) {
    var hex = dec.toString(16);
    alert(hex);
}
else {
    alert("number must be greater than 0");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var dec = prompt("Enter a number");

if (dec != null && dec > 0) {
    var hex = parseInt(dec,16);
    alert(hex);
}
else {
    alert("number must be greater than 0");
}
```

Comment: nothing just convert dec string to number. This is another way by using you can convert dec into hex.